# Uniqueness of the damped wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to prove the uniqueness of the following.

\begin{cases} u_{tt} + u_t - u_{xx} = 0 & 0<x<b, t>0 \\
u(0,t) = u_x(b,t) = 0 & t\geq 0 \\
u(x,0) = f(x), u_t(x,0) = g(x) & 0\leq x\leq b
\end{cases}

My attempt is as follows.

For two solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$, let $w = u_1 - u_2$. Define the energy $$E = \frac 1 2 \int_0^b w_t^2 + w_x^2 dx $$
Then, $$E'(t) = -\int_0^b w_t^2 + (w_tw_x)_xdx = -\int_0^b w_t^2\,dx - w_t(0,t)w_x(0,t) $$ 
Then, I am lost. Even if $E'(t)=0$, $E(0) \neq 0$. How do I proceed?

Comment: What are $w_t$ and $w_x$? I suppose the derivatives of $w$, but what is $w$?

Comment: I'm sorry, I added.

Comment: So $E(0)=0$, because the two solutions have to satisfy the same initial conditions.

Comment: Why should it be satisfied?

Comment: A solution of an initial-boundary values problem is a function satisfying the equation and all boundary and initial conditions. So if $u_1$ and $u_2$ are solutions, have to satisty the equation and all boundary and initial conditions.

Comment: I got it, thanks! In a similar way, should $w_t(b,t)w_x(b,t)$ be equal to $w_t(0,t)w_x(b,t)?